# How to properly handle non-existent named route?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am using the Vue Router in my project. When i link to a route whose name does not exist, so for example:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'test-route' }"> link </router-link>
```

Vue complains in the console saying:

> [vue-router] Route with name 'test-route' does not exist

But nothing happens to the user to indicate that something is wrong. The address bar gets changed to the root route (just `/`), but without the homepage actually showing, and my `router.onError` handler (which usually handles trying to navigate to lazy loaded components when you lose connection) doesn't fire in this case.

I want to show on screen that something is wrong, a redirection to my 404 page if nothing else.

Comment: That's a bizarre edge-case. Why would you, the author of your app, create a link to a named route that does not exist? I believe the current handling of such a case is adequate. This is a developer error

Comment: Old links to pages that later get removed for example... Developer error definitely, but in the context of the question i'll take it your comment means this cannot be handled in a "UI way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion - don't allow a link to be clickable if it is not valid, you can make a condition inside the `v-on` directive.
`v-on="{ to: <does link exist (access router)> ? { name: 'test-route' } : null}"`.
Might need some syntax fixing but that's the general idea.